# Why whois parsed output with python is not written to a text file?

Tags: python, text, printing, whois

I am writing the below python script to parse whois data for a list of domain names that I have in a separate file. Here is the script:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import whois
from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList

file = '/data/personal/Mae-git-domains.txt'
output = '/data/personal/whois-Mae.txt'

psl = PublicSuffixList()

f = open (file,'r')

for line in f:
    url = line.split('   ')[1]
    domain = url.split('http://')[1].split('/')[0]
    try:
        w =whois.whois(domain)
        results = domain,w.creation_date,w.expiration_date


        with open (output,'wb') as m:
            m.write(results.text)
#            print ("%s,%s,%s" % (domain,w.creation_date,w.expiration_date), file = m )
#            print >> m ,"%s|%s|%s" % (domain,w.creation_date,w.expiration_date)
#            m.write("{0},{0},{0}".format(domain,w.creation_date,w.expiration_date))

    except:
#            print ("%s,%s,%s" % (domain,[],[]), file = m )
        pass
```

It gets printed when I print it on the terminal but not when I am trying to either write or print it into a text file (the other printing/writing attempts are in the code as comments). Does any one have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: All of your methods of writing to a file are valid and should work, are you getting an exception when you write to a file? Maybe a permission error or something?

Comment: @kalhartt No am not getting any exception.

Comment: @kalhartt can it be the case that something cannot be written in the format of %s string? maybe that is the problem?

Comment: it is possible (but unlikely), and that would also give you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

to write it into a text file you can use `m.write(str(results.text))` , you basically need to force it to be a string because its of type unicode.